# Logcat randomly not logging: Eclipse 4.2.0 and android-sdk_r20.0.3-macosx

Tags: android, eclipse

Everything was fine until all I did was update my android tools. Has anyone else experienced `Logcat` in `Eclipse` randomly not logging? If you check the shell `adb logcat` everything logs as normal, but for whatever reason `Eclipse logcat` just fails randomly. It's not very reproducible, but it happens often enough to make development harder.

As a test I did:

```
onCreate() {
   Log.i("MyClass", "1");
   /// and kept incrementing the number to 20.
```

And it would fail about 30% of the time.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I'm running the latest of everything and on OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: when you run your project on device or emulator, go to DDMS perspective and click on the device on which you have run your project and see the logcat. I also face this many a times..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the activity each time?! i mean try to log something in loop and see if still problem exists.
if yes then try to install eclipse again